# Optimum number of processes to write a large number of files simultaneosly

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to write a very large number of files simultaneously (say 10000 files). I found that I can use multiprocessing for that. I arbitrarily chose to use 100 processes to write these files. I need to know if there is a way to find the optimum number of processes to use? Also do I need to do any cleanup after this code or all the processes get terminated automatically?

I'd also like to know if there is a more efficient way to write this large number of files simultaneously.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def write(x):
    fopen=open('file_'+str(x),'w')
    fopen.write('anything')
    fopen.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=100)              
    pool.map(write, range(10000))
```

Comment: Why don't you test it with different values and compare the results? I think this would be highly dependent on what hardware you run it on also.

Comment: That's why I am asking, I tried a few values and 100 seemed to give the best results, but I don't know if it is possible to tell based on the hardware specifications what is the optimum number of processes to use

Comment: With most hardware, for files of a reasonable size, you probably won't notice much speed-up whether you have 10 or 100 processes writing at a time since your can only pack data onto your disk at a maximum rate.

Comment: Is the machine using an SSD by chance?

Comment: If you're doing pure I/O like this, `threading` is likely to be at least as good as `multiprocessing`, and often better, and has no mysteries about "do I need to do any cleanup", so you might want to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for pure I/O, `threading` is likely to be as good as `multiprocessing`, and often better. It also has no mysteries about "do I need any cleanup". So, you might want to test that.

Second, if you want to know the fastest way to do this, the only real option is to test, using `timeit`, or maybe your shell's `time` or an equivalent. And it sounds ike you're already doing that. If you're looking for a way to programmatically determine the ideal pool size based on info you can read about the system (SSD vs. 10K HD vs. 5200 HD vs. remote share, LAN vs. WAN, fast LAN vs. slow LAN, SMB vs. NFS, Windows vs. POSIX, etc.), you'll probably need to test on a wide variety of machines and do some statistical analysis. And some of that information isn't available statically, so you'd really need to start the process and then adjust the pool size as you go. It's going to be very complicated—and I'd guess that all that work is only going to get you a 10% benefit most of the time.

If you really need to squeeze the last few percentage points out of file I/O, you may have to drop down a level or two.

At the very least, you may want to drop the Python and/or stdio buffers out of the equation (assuming the files really are this small) and use `os.open` and `os.write`. It may even be helpful to create a raw buffer of bytes instead of a string (especially if this is Python 3). If you're actually writing the exact same thing to every file, or even just to many files, using the same buffer may allow the OS to recognize that you're writing the same thing to multiple files, meaning the caching can be perfect instead of just close to perfect.

You might even want to drop down to platform-specific APIs. For example, on Windows, using overlapped I/O allows the OS to schedule the writes as efficiently as possible, and creating a native threadpool around an IOCP to handle the completions removes also all overhead on top of the write scheduling. (You can access `CreateFile`, `WriteFileEx`, etc. via `ctypes` or `win32api`. Or google for "IOCP Python" for sample code—which will all be incomplete or partially irrelevant, especially since most of it is designed for doing c10k socket servers, but it will at least demonstrate enough to put the rest together yourself, with some help from MSDN and trial and error.) I can't think of anything equivalent on POSIX (well, `aio_write` is the equivalent to `WriteFileEx`, but it's not going to help performance on any real-world *nix platform, as far as I know).

Alternatively, you might want to move *up* a step. If you're really writing the same data to all, or just many, files, why not just write it to one file and then ask the OS to copy that file? It may be able to do a better job.

Or, even simpler—and a whole lot faster—write it to one file and then create the rest as hard links or symlinks.

---

Since you asked about the last option:

The idea behind creating a link is that you only create one file, but create 10000 different names to access it under.

This means that if you edit one file, all 10000 are edited. If that's not what you want, links aren't appropriate.

But if it is what you want, there are two basic kinds of links: hard links, and symbolic links.

Modern filesystems allow multiple directory entries to point to the same file. Creating a [hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) is a way of creating another directory entry that points to the same file as an existing one. In Python, you do this with [`os.link`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.link). So:

```
with open('file_0', 'w') as f:
    f.write('anything')
for i in range(1, 10000):
    os.link('file_0', 'file_{}'.format(i))
```

Now your filesystem has 10000 entries named `file_0` through `file_9999`, but they're all names for the same actual data on disk. Edit one, and the other 9999 all change. Delete one, and the other 9999 are still there.

There are some minor issues with hard links, and one major one. The minor issues are that each platform has different rules about hard linking things besides regular files, and you generally can't hard link across filesystems. The major issue is Windows. First, you need something like (off the top of my head) Vista and NTFS 6 for full support, Win2000 and NTFS 4 for partial support. But, more importantly, `os.link` doesn't exist on Windows. So, you have to use `ctypes` or `win32api` to call the underlying `CreateHardLink` function (or `subprocess` to run the `mklink` or `fsutil` command).

A [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) is higher-level idea. It's a special kind of file that references another file by path. This means you can read information about a symlink itself (see `stat` vs. `lstat`), create a tarball that preserves link information, etc. It also means that if you delete `file_0`, all of the others become broken links pointing at a file that isn't there. Anyway, in Python, you use [`os.symlink`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.symlink) to create them (with the exact same code as above).

Symlinks are free of most of the limitations of hard links, but they're even worse for Windows—no symlinks at all before Vista, different rules for plain files vs. directories, limits on number of links that can be traversed, requires special privileges which non-admin users don't have, etc. And of course you can't use `os.symlink` from Python.

There are also some platform-specific things like Windows shortcuts and Mac aliases that have similar but not identical features to symlinks.

Comment: this looks all very useful and opens up several possible directions...out of which I am interested in the possibility of writing to one single file and create the rest as hard links or symlinks, how do you do that??

Comment: @hmghaly: I'll edit the answer to include more info. But it would help if you mentioned what platform(s) you care about. Just POSIX? POSIX and Windows, but only Vista and later? Everything?

Comment: I'm using mainly windows, but some applications should be also running on my linux server